# Notepad++ find and replace number, digit format

Tags: numbers, format, notepad++

I have single and two digit number, and I want to make it 4 digits.

So "1" become "0001", "22" become "0022"

How do I do that?

Comment: I only got part way there.  Select regular expression with Find: ([1-9]{1,3}) Replace: (0\1).  However that doesn't ignore numbers that already have a leading zero or add the correct number of leading zeros.  Seems the regular expression in NotePad doesn't know the ^ (not).

Answer (score 3):

You have to do two replacements:

```
search: \b(\d\d)\b
replace: 00$1
```

and:

```
search: \b(\d)\b
replace: 000$1
```

Comment: And if you want to apply the same replacements in multiple files, you could record a Macro.

Comment: This expression works fine when i put `\b(\d\d)\b` in the `mark` tab. but in `replace` tab I give no result while regular expression is selected as search mode.

Comment: @ir-tech:Sorry, I don't get you. Could you explain what do you mean? In what context,  It is better to ask a new question with a sample input file, what you get and what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Generalising the question. Suppose we want to convert a collection of numbers so that all have, say, 7 digits by adding leading zeroes as necessary. This can be done in two steps.

1. Add 7 leading zeroes to each number, so eg `2 33 456 789012` becomes  `00000002 000000033 0000000456 0000000789012`.
2. Convert each number to have the required number of digits by removing some leading zeroes to leave the wanted 7 digits.

In more detail.

1. Search for `\b(\d{1,6})\b` which finds numbers with between 1 and 6 digits inclusive. Replace them with `0000000\1`. There is no need to search for 7-digit numbers as they are already the correct length.
2. Search for `\b0+(\d{7})\b` and replace with `\1`.

Notes

- Input numbers that have more than 7 digits will not be found by step 1.
- Input numbers that have leading zeros with less than 7 significant digits, e.g. `001234` will have the 7 zeroes added by step 1 whereas `00000000000001234` is longer than 7 digits and so will not be changed by step 1.
- Input numbers with leading zeroes and more than 7 significant digits will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I used \1 instead of $1

First Replacement:

```
search: (\d\d)
replace: 00\1
```

Second Replacement:

```
search: (\d)
replace: 000\1
```