# How to pad a character to different length of columns in notepad++ for GPS coordinates

Tags: text, notepad++, text-editor

I have coordinates like these:

```
28.62834,41.11797,0  // every line must be at this lenght
28.62881,41.11737,0
28.6289,41.11725,0   // must add 0 (zero) to 28.6289 , it should look like this: 28.62890
28.62898,41.11716,0
28.629,41.11688,0    // must add two 0 (zero) to 28.629 , it should look like this: 28.62900
28.62935,41.1167,0
28.62978,41.11615,0
28.62996,41.11593,0
28.630,41.115,0      // must add two 0 (zero) to 28.630 , it should look like this: 28.63000 and must add two 0 (zero) to 41.115 , it should look like this: 41.11500,
```

I want to add 0 (zero) to latitude and longitude values to make each line at same lenght.
Latitude and longitude must have **5 numbers** after the dot. Example: 28.XXXXX,41.XXXXX

What I want:

```
28.62834,41.11797,0
28.62881,41.11737,0
28.62890,41.11725,0
28.62898,41.11716,0
28.62900,41.11688,0
28.62935,41.11670,0
28.62978,41.11615,0
28.62996,41.11593,0
28.63000,41.11500,0
```

Is there an easy way to this in notepad++?

Comment: There is a condratiction between the rule: “Latitude and longitude must have 5 numbers after the dot.” and the example `28.62935,41.1167,0` that becomes `28.629350,41.1167,0`

Comment: I fixed `28.629350` . It must be `28.62935`.  There must be 5 numbers after the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps.

First add zeros after every number that is too short. Do a regex replace of `\b(\d\d\.\d{0,4}),` with `${1}00000,`.

Second remove excess zeroes. Do a regex replace of `\b(\d\d\.\d{5})0+,` with `$1,`.

Explanation:

The first regex finds two digits followed by a dot then zero to four move digits and finally a comma. There is no need to look for five digits after the dot. The replacement ensures that every number has at least five digits.

The second regex is similar to the first, but it finds numbers with five digits after the dot and then some zeros and finally a comma.

This is much the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869259/546871), but the regexs add/remove zeros on the right.

Comment: This answer assumes that the output line `28.629350,41.1167,0` (that @Toto commented upon) is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `format.py`):

```
import re
def format(match):
    nums = match.group(1).split(',')
    return "%7.5f,%7.5f;%d" % (float(nums[0]), float(nums[1]), int(nums[2]) )
editor.rereplace('^(.+)$', format)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> format)
- Done

**Assuming that** `28.629350,41.1167,0` must be `28.62935,41.11670,0`

**Result for given example:**

[image]

Comment: I tried your answer. But I got "Access violation" error. I unsinstall the plugin and reinstalled it a few times. @AdrianHHH 's answer worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @emert117: Too bad :( may be a version problem or configuration, here:  Windows 10, Npp 7.8.4 64bit PythonScript 1.3